# Having a POST'able API and Django's CSRF Middleware

Tags: django, security, api, csrf

I have a Django webapp that has both a front-end, web-accessible component and an API that is accessed by a desktop client.  However, now with the new CSRF middleware component, API requests from the desktop client that are POST'ed get a 403.

I understand why this is happening, but what is the proper way to fix this without compromising security?  Is there someway I can signal in the HTTP header that it's an API request and that Django shouldn't be checking for CSRF or is that a bad strategy?

***Edit--***

The method I'm using at the moment is that the desktop client sets a header, X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest.  This is kinda hacky, but I'm not sure how this would be handled better.

Comment: since your temporal solution (from last edit) is basically turning off csrf, you can turn off the middleware completely, don't you? :)

Comment: It needs to be on for the rest of the site (the front-end portion)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about just splitting off a view(s) for your desktop client and decorating them with [csrf_exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/#ref-contrib-csrf)?

Comment: That is exactly the setup but `csrf_exempt` doesn't seem to make a difference.  It still gives a 403 with that decorator.  +1 because according to the doc this should be working, even though it's not.

Comment: This is ONLY valid if the API can't be accessed through the browser. Otherwise this is potentially super dangerous as a request could then be forged from another site, against the API.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using a Class Based View then you will need to csrf_exempt the dispatch method rather than the post method like this:

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(MyView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

See this bug ticket:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15794

Answer (score -3):

Since Django 1.1, the CSRF code will automatically allow AJAX requests to pass through, since browsers seem to do proper security checks. Here is the [original commit](http://github.com/django/django/commit/eb4cbff7ce84ab20ee9c22eab5a8478acffb2651) and the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax).

Comment: Hm, that's not true, is it? In the link you provided, it does say you need to add an extra header for AJAX to work, not that it works automatically.