# Django REST framework JWT 403 forbidden

Tags: django, django-rest-framework-jwt

I've gone through the installation steps in the django-rest-framework-jwt docs and I am unable to run the curl $ curl -X POST -d "username=admin&password=abc123" http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/. I CANNOT get back the token! Instead I got back CSRF cookie error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
  <title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="summary">
        <h1>Forbidden <span>(403)</span></h1>
        <p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>
        <p>You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.</p>
        <p>If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for &#39;same-origin&#39; requests.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="info">
        <h2>Help</h2>
        <p>Reason given for failure:</p>
        <pre>CSRF cookie not set.</pre>
        <p>In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when <a href="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/">Django's CSRF mechanism</a> has not been used correctly.  For POST forms, you need to ensure:</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Your browser is accepting cookies.</li>
            <li>The view function passes a <code>request</code> to the template's <a href="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.base.Template.render"><code>render</code></a> method.</li>
            <li>In the template, there is a <code>{% csrf_token %}</code> template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL.</li>
            <li>If you are not using <code>CsrfViewMiddleware</code>, then you must use <code>csrf_protect</code> on any views that use the <code>csrf_token</code> template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.</li>
        </ul>

        <p>You're seeing the help section of this page because you have <code>DEBUG = True</code> in your Django settings file. Change that to <code>False</code>, and only the initial error message will be displayed.  </p>
        <p>You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a POST simple JSON using Django REST Framework? CSRF token missing or incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507206/how-to-make-a-post-simple-json-using-django-rest-framework-csrf-token-missing-o)

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306515/how-to-curl-an-authenticated-django-app/24376188#24376188