# Getting CSRF error when sending POST Request using Postman [LOGIN PAGE]

Tags: django, rest, csrf, postman

While the site loads smoothly through the browser,but when i send a POST request via postman or a REST API client, i am getting a csrf error.

"CSRF cookie not set."

IS THERE A WAY TO SEND A REQUEST SKIPPING CSRF?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django CSRF Cookie Not Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716624/django-csrf-cookie-not-set)

Comment: Duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507206/how-to-make-a-post-simple-json-using-django-rest-framework-csrf-token-missing-o

Answer (score 1):

You need to use csrf_exempt decorator on your view : this will disable the check of the csrf token

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt