# Django: Set crsf token while making POST request from rest client

Tags: django, rest, django-csrf

I'm using the chrome rest client to test the api calls.

A GET request is working fine but while making a `POST` request , getting `403 hidden` response.
description is

```
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted
```

I'm setting as `Content-Type=application/json`.

One way would be to use @csrf_extempt, but seems to be good choice.

How to resolve above issue ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having a POST'able API and Django's CSRF Middleware](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405353/having-a-postable-api-and-djangos-csrf-middleware)

Comment: i mentioned in post that @csrf_extempt, is not a good choice. so that post is not meet solution.

Comment: If you have make your posts with ajax, then you can get `csrf_token` data with javascript and add it to your post. But, in your case, there would be no cookie, and only solution is using `@csrf_extempt` as @ArpitSingh mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Using @csrf_extempt is infact a good practice when you are providing an API to your site. Cross-site request forgery is what csrf is but in your case it won't be a forgery since an api can(should) be called from any site but yours.
.
Moreover sharing csrf token will prove to be very tricky.

Answer (score 0):

In thre request, include an *X-CSRFToken* header with the CSRF token value obtained from the *csrftoken* cookie.

Comment: how to get this csrftoken cookie ?

Comment: either by javascript by examining `document.cookie`, or look in the Cookies section of the *Resources* tab in the Chrome developer tools (Chrome menu button -> Tools -> Developer Tools)

Comment: ah true, if you're using Chrome REST client.  Django assumes an initial GET request for a web app, which would have had the *csrftoken* cookie set.  Go with Arpit's answer :)